# How should I search for characters within a 2D char array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have two char arrays: (Magic numbers used for clarity)

```
char Intermediary[121];
char RI[20][7];
```

I copied the contents of Intermediary to RI with the following code: (Bear in mind each row needs a null deliminator (20 * (7 - 1)) = 121 - 1)

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;

for( a=0; a<20; a++ )
{
    for( b=0; b<6; b++ )
    {
        RI[a][b] = Intermediary[c++];
    }

    RI[a][6] = '\0';

 }
```

I intended to use strchr for this, checking if e.g. RI[0][0] to RI[0][7] contains y. If it turns out that y cannot be found within that range, the program should iterate to the characters between RI[1][0] and RI[1][7].

However, strchr takes a pointer as an argument, instead of a char array.

How do I make a pointer, in which I can iterate through each row?

On a side note, if anyone wants extra brownie points, is my code converting the 1D array to a 2D array correct?

Comment: `strchr` needs null terminated strings. It's not clear from the posted code that `RI` contains null terminated strings.

Comment: @RSahu I mentioned it between the two blocks of code

Comment: `&RI[x][0]` gives you the address of the xth 'string', where RI is an array of 20 'strings' containing up to 6 characters with a '\0' terminator.

Comment: By the way, I hope you mean `RI[0][0]` to `RI[0][6]`, because the 2nd dimension of your array is 7, which means valid indeces are 0 to 6 (inclusively).  Also, the 7th element (index 6) will be '\0', so you'll only be checking elements 0 to 5 (the first 6) for `y`.

Comment: @Wouldn'tYouLikeToKnow your code to copy `Intermediary` into `RI` is wrong

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Why? 0 to 19 is a range of 20..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find a character `chr` on a given row `a` you would use

```
char *pch;

pch = strchr( RI[a], chr );
if(pch)
{
    // character found; pch is a pointer to it.
}
else
{
    // character not found
}
```

`RI[a]` is a pointer to the first element of the row that may also be expressed as `&(RI[a][0])`

But first you have to fix your while loop since is not doing what you stated in your question (making a NULL terminated string for each row).

I suggest this fixed version, rewritten using with two `for` loops:

```
for( a=0; a<20; a++ )
{
    for( b=0; b<6; b++ )
    {
        RI[a][b] = Intermediary[c++];
    }
    RI[a][6] = '\0';
 }
```

Comment: Why have the ternary operator in the internal loop?  You could replace it with `RI[a][b] = Intermediary[c++];` and have a `RI[a][b] = '\0';` statement immediately after the closing brace of the loop, eliminating the extra test each time round the loop.

Comment: ...and change the loop to `for (b=0; b<6; b++)`.

Comment: @Paolo thanks for your code, I'm going to test it now

Answer (score 0):

The code to copy the characters from `Intermediary` to `RI` needs to be fixed to make sure that `RI` contains null terminated strings.

```
while (c != 121)
{
    if (b == 6) /* Go to the next column, the first element */
    {
        RI[a][b] = '\0'; // Make sure that R[a] is null terminated.
        ++a;
        b = 0;
    }                   

    RI[a][b] = Intermediary[c];

    ++b;        /* Iterate to next letter of RebuiltIntermediary */
    ++c;        /* Iterate to next letter of Intermediary */
}
```

Now you can use `RI` to search for `y` using:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 21; ++i )
{
    if ( strchr(RI[i], 'y') != NULL )
    {
       // 'y' found. Do what you need to do.
    }
}
```

Comment: when `b == 6` you don't have to increment `c`

Comment: @Paolo incrementing `c` is necessary no matter what the value of `b` is. That's the index for iterating over the items in `Intermediary`.

Comment: @R Sahu read better what the OP wrote and look at the size of the arrays: `Intermediary` is 20 rows of 6 characters (120 bytes) plus a null termination (total 121). So rows in `Intermediary` are not NULL terminated except the last one. Every row in `RI` is NULL terminated in fact its size is 20 x 7 = 140: 20 rows of 6 characters + a NULL termination.

Comment: @Paolo. `RI[0][0] .. RI[0][5]` contain the first `6` characters for `Intermidiary. Hence `RI[0][6]` needs to be `'\0'`. It doesn't change the logic for incrementing `c`. Walk through the code and you will see that my logic is sound.

Answer (score -1):

A good example can be found here.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/

In order to search every line, you can use a for loop to iterate through each line and using the example from above, input each line (as a string) to the strchr function independently. A modified version of the above example that does that with a smaller matrix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char str2[3][3] = {{'a','b','c'},{'d','a','f'},{'g','a','i'}};

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        char * pch;

        char str[3]={};

        for (int j=0;j<3;j++) str[j] = str2[i][j];

        char qw = 'a';

        printf ("Looking for the %c character in line %d...\n",qw,i);

        pch=strchr(str,qw);

        while (pch!=NULL)
        {
            printf ("found at %d\n",pch-str+1);
            pch=strchr(pch+1,'s');
        }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps. Best regards.